# Unable to access the printer when hosting to iis

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, iis-6

I am using rdlc report in MVC,Printing operation works perfectly when running in visual studio, but when published to iis which is set up in the same machine,printing operation is not taking place.But when I return the report as pdf the report it is there,and I can print the file using javascript.But I actually need not want to display the report but want to print from server..Thanks For help in advance

```
  public ActionResult GenerateOrder()
    {


        try
        {

            LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
            report.ReportPath = (Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Report1.rdlc"));
            Export(report);
            Print();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {

        }

        return View();
    }

    private Stream CreateStream(string name,
    string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding,
    string mimeType, bool willSeek)
    {
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        m_streams.Add(stream);
        return stream;
    }
     private void Export(LocalReport report)
    {
        string deviceInfo =
          @"<DeviceInfo>
            <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
            <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>
            <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>
            <MarginTop>0.25in</MarginTop>
            <MarginLeft>0.25in</MarginLeft>
            <MarginRight>0.25in</MarginRight>
            <MarginBottom>0.25in</MarginBottom>
        </DeviceInfo>";
        Warning[] warnings;
        m_streams = new List<Stream>();
        report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream,
           out warnings);
        foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
            stream.Position = 0;
    }
    private int m_currentPageIndex;
    private IList<Stream> m_streams;

    private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        try
        {
            Metafile pageImage = new
                        Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);

            // Adjust rectangular area with printer margins.
            Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
                ev.PageBounds.Left - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
                ev.PageBounds.Top - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
                ev.PageBounds.Width,
                ev.PageBounds.Height);

            // Draw a white background for the report
            ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

            // Draw the report content
            ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect);

            // Prepare for the next page. Make sure we haven't hit the end.
            m_currentPageIndex++;
            ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex < m_streams.Count);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
   private void Print()
    {
        if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("Error: no stream to print.");
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
        }
        else
        {

            PrinterSettings pset = new PrinterSettings();
            printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
            m_currentPageIndex = 0;
            printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = pset.PrinterName;
            printDoc.Print();
        }
    }
```

Comment: this may help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290045(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help@pranav, I have tried this but not solved my issue..:(

Comment: can you please share your print code?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20870330/5358389

Comment: @daniell89 I have tried it but not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to print the page from Server itself. Check the **Identity** under which your application is running. If it is running under default account then change it to either **your account** or to a **different account** that has printer access.

Go to IIS,
(a) First find the **Application Pool** your app is using
(b) And then go to **Application Pool** details and find the **Identity** it is using. (c) Change this Identity to your/some other account that has printer access.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I tried for administrator account but not working.. :(

Comment: You are suppressing all the exceptions with (empty catch blocks). Can you add some logging in your exception blocks and find out the exact error it is throwing?

Comment: It is working when I changed the admin user to normal user.. thank you alot.. :)