# How to change preferences for IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool

Tags: windows, iis, user-permissions

I want to be able to change IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool user settings like I can change settings on my normal Windows account. Specifically, I would like to change some printer settings for the IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool user. Is this possible? If this is possible, how would one go about accomplishing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "IIS user"? That's not an accurate term to use in IIS context.

Comment: Lex Li, IIS user simply refers to the user account that IIS services run under. I do not know its exact name.

Comment: Then you created a second wrong term. There is no "IIS services" either. If you don't know the name, please go over IIS documentation first to make sure you find the right words for a question, https://learn.microsoft.com/iis or there would be no answer.

Comment: Lex Li, the user is "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870316/asp-net-iis-server-side-printing-fails